# locally-installed PDF.JS does not render

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

When trying to use PDF.JS from npm-installed pdfjs, a pdf is not rendering without any errors displayed to the console.

When using the online source (e.g. `//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js`), a PDF is rendered just fine.

This is the code I'm using, taken almost directly from [this example](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/#interactive-examples):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>PDF.js 'Hello, world!' example</h1>
<canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>

<script>
    var url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ ba2edeae/examples/learning/helloworld.pdf';

    // Loaded via <script> tag, create shortcut to access PDF.js exports.
    var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];

    // The workerSrc property shall be specified.
    pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js';

    // Asynchronous download of PDF
    var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url);
    loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
        console.log('PDF loaded');

        // Fetch the first page
        var pageNumber = 1;
        pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
        console.log('Page loaded');

        var scale = 1.5;
        var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});

        // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
        var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        // Render PDF page into canvas context
        var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: context,
            viewport: viewport
        };
        var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
        renderTask.promise.then(function () {
            console.log('Page rendered');
        });
    });
}, function (reason) {
    // PDF loading error
    console.error(reason);
});

</script>
```

This was through the remote version of PDFJS
[image: Through remote PDFJS]

This was through the local(npm) version
[image: Local version of PDFJS]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly the error you came across while implementing the above code. To be more specific - a console error in browser.

I was implementing the same way as yours i.e locally but not using node-modules. I had downloaded latest dist folder from PDFJS site - https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

I made below changes in order to work the code as it works in demo

1) Copied contents from https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js and saved into a JS file pdf.js

2) Included the files in HTML page at top

```
<script src="pdfjs-2.2.228-dist/build"></script>
<script src="pdf.js"></script>
```

Here pdfjs-2.2.228-dist is a folder which is downloaded from site.

3) In script commented the pdfjsLib assignment and declaration

```
// Loaded via <script> tag, create shortcut to access PDF.js exports.
//var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];
```

4) workerSrc url modified by appending http to it

```
// The workerSrc property shall be specified.
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';
```

I haven't tried but changing url to path `pdfjs-2.2.228-dist/build/pdf.worker.js` should also work.

Hopefully this helps to you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing through the js script, if you have access to HTML, then you can directly embed this code in the body section to display the user-friendly pdf Viewer as discussed in [this](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2018/render-pdfs-in-the-browser-with-pdf-js/) article.

```
<iframe
    src="path-to-viewer-inside-web-folder/viewer.html?file=path-to-pdf-file/test.pdf"
    width="800px"
    height="600px"
    style="border: none;" />
```